# Any way to check the integrity of a Wordpress site?

Tags: errors, installation

is there any way to check if the installation has gone well or if there is something wrong with the backend of WP?

I've gone into a few errors and I've tried to reinstall Wordpress within the 'Upgrade' pane and it doesn't work for some reason, so I have no idea what is going on.

I'd like to do this because there are several things that are really odd that has been going on in my site, that I've never experienced before in many previous installations on 2 other (old) hosts. I'm not sure whether it's a permissions problem but all I know is that the installation has messed up and I want to find out what has gone wrong.

Examples:

- Missing .htaccess, although host allows it.
- In Settings, some settings cannot be changed or instantly reverts back to the default option.
- Cannot reinstall from the 'Upgrade' pane.

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress is pretty solid, usually misconfigurations get in the way. You want to make sure:

1. you have your wp-config.php file properly set
2. your database is accessible
3. that your `home` and `siteurl` settings are properly set in `wp_options` table
4. sometimes a plugin fouls things up, you can disable all plugins by unsetting `active_plugins` in the `wp_options` table, you can the reenable one by one
5. you can set `WP_DEBUG` to `true`, this may give you a clue

Answer (score 0):

I like to install the iThemes plugin called serverBuddy. Here is a quick run down of what it does and links to download it: http://pluginbuddy.com/serverbuddy-check-hosting-quality-security-issues-more/